# AppleScript code works on High Sierra, but not on Monterey

Tags: macos, applescript, macos-high-sierra, macos-monterey

I want to look into a folder to select every file whose name contains "abc".

Here is my AppleScript code:

```
set myFolder to (((path to library folder from user domain) as string) & "FOLDER") as alias

tell application "Finder"

    set deleted123 to every file of folder myFolder whose name contains "abc"
        repeat with oneFile in deleted123
        if exists (deleted123) then set end of deleted123 to oneFile & return
        --Do something
        end repeat
    
    if deleted123 ≠ {} then
        --Do something else with the selected.
    end if
end tell
```

The code works flawlessly on High Sierra, i.e., it finds out all the files whose names contain "abc", but it doesn't on Monterey.

What is the problem? How can this piece of code be improved?

Help highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are two major mistakes:

1. `myFolder` is an alias specifier. You add the `folder` keyword which is  a double reference, delete `as alias` in the first line
2. `oneFile` is a Finder file specifier, you cannot append the string `return`. Maybe the file specifier is silently coerced to string in Sierra. If you want to use the file references then the `return` statement makes no sense anyway.

Another bad practice is to modify the array `deleted123` while being enumerated. Create an extra variable.

And the repeat loop makes no sense either because `exists (deleted123)` is always `true` and even if you check the current item in the loop `oneFile` it's always `true`.